# Looping through UID's in a rxjs stream and mapping resolved results?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

i recently wrote this code to grab a uid from the orginal returned data, and then fetch more data using that uid and return an object.

This works great, but i also have keys in the round Object of many uid's i would need to do the same thing but loop over them and get all the data.

Any guidance on how i could do this? i tryed many different ways but i kept getting returned observables.

```
getRound(roundUid: string) {

  /**
    Retrieves a round based simply on the uid
    supplied.
  **/

  return this.fb.round(roundUid)
    .mergeMap(round => // Get Serie Data
      this.fb.serie(round['serieUid']).map(serie => {round['serie'] = this.cs.cleanForFb(serie); return round})
    )
    .mergeMap(round => // Get Type Data
      this.fb.type(round['typeUid']).map(type => {round['type'] = this.cs.cleanForFb(type); return round})
    )
    .mergeMap(round => // Get sx Coast Data
      this.fb.coast(round['sxCoastUid']).map(sxCoast => {round['sxCoast'] = this.cs.cleanForFb(sxCoast); return round})
    )
}
```

As below i'd need too:

```
  return this.fb.round(roundUid)
    .mergeMap(round => 
      // LOOP THROUGH 'round.riderUids' WHICH IS AN OBJECT OF MANY //
    )
```

Comment: can't you use the operator from()? like Observable.from(round.riderUids).map(type => {round['type'] = this.cs.cleanForFb(type); return round}). That should create one observable per value

Comment: I will try this here soon, thanks

Comment: 'ERROR TypeError: object is not observable
    at Function.FromObservable.create [as from] '

Is all i get, i can use of, but i get the object back, i need to loop through

Comment: can you provide some data and some code?